# Localize FlipView binded to data in C#

Tags: c#, json, localization, win-universal-app

I'm developing an `UWP` app in `C#`. It needs to support both English and French and the first screen contains a `FlipView` bound to JSON data.

How could I localize the text content inside this `FlipView`?

I have thought of multiple ways:

- In the `JSON`, add translated fields for each view. This means I'll need to retrieve the current language and change the way I parse the `JSON` according to it.
- Do another JSON and choose which one to parse according to the language I retrieve.

What would you do and what is the most efficient? Is there another way? As I'm already using `XAML` resource files to translate other UI strings. If there is not, is there a way to retrieve language information in `C#`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just made it so that there is a JSON file for each language. I then switch the file according to the system language at load time.

Answer (score 0):

well there is not easy way to solve your problem.

You will need translate the words of your json manually but I recommend you to use Bing Translator Api is very easy to use.

you can send your word to be translated to another language ans show the result in your UI

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx